# Reading the kanji database kradfile into R: encoding problem

Tags: r, utf-8, cjk

I am trying to load the [kradfile](http://www.edrdg.org/krad/kradinf.html) into R like this:

```
krad<-readLines("kradfile2",encoding = "UTF-8")
krad<-readLines("kradfile2",encoding = "EUC-JP")
```

but neither seem to do the trick in properly reading the content. I have no idea about what to do with the encoding to read it properly.
The file has this instructions:

```
[20] "# Two fonts were used in decomposition so as to include as many glyphs as"     
[21] "# possible.  One apparently based on the JIS X 0212 standard itself, and"      
[22] "# one based on Unicode.  Each JIS X 0212 kanji is represented by 3 bytes"      
[23] "# in EUC-JP encoding, as opposed to the two bytes used in the JIS X 0208"      
[24] "# range, so adjust your software accordingly if necessary."
```

the encoded text looks like this:

```
 : °ì Ò± °¢ : °ì ¡Ã °£ : °ì ¡Ã °¤ : °ì ¡Ã ¥Î °¥ : °ì Ð¦ ¥Î Ò± °¦ : ÒÓ ²¦ °§ : °ì ¡Ã ¥Î ¸ý °¨ : °ì ¿Í ÑÄ °© : ¡Ã °ª : ¡Ã Ð¦ ¥Î Öõ °« : ¡Ã Æó °¬ : ¡Ã ×Ä °­ : °ì ¡Ã Æó °® : °ì Ð¦ ¥Î Öõ ½½ ´³ °¯ : Ð¦ °° : °ì Ð¦ °± : Ð¦ ¥Î °² : °ì ¥Î ²µ °³ : ¡Ã Ð¦ ¥Î °´ : ²µ °µ : ²µ Ò¸ °¶ : ²µ Öö °· : ²µ ÒÓ ¸ý °¸ : ²µ ËÎ ¸ý °¹ : °ì ¥Î ²µ Ð­ ¶Ô °º : ²µ ½½ Î© ¿É °» : ²µ ½½ Æü °¼ :
```

help apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file looks a little weird, being a mix of JIS X 0208-1997 encodings for the Japanese characters and plain one-byte ASCII for the descriptive text and spaces, so it looks as though you'll have to detect and decode the pairs of bytes for each Japanese character separately from the rest of the file.

For example, line 200 of the file looks like this:

```
"\xb1\xa4 : \xb2\xbb \xb3\xad \xcc\xdc \xa5\xcf \xb8\xfd \xc6\xfc Ω"
```

I don't know the JIS X 0208 encoding, but I'm pretty sure this isn't legal in it:  it's a 2 byte per character encoding for all characters, not just the Japanese part.  So you would need to read the file as bytes and parse them yourself.

Luckily, someone else has already done that.  You can get a UTF-8 version of the file here:  https://github.com/irrwahn/jiten-pai/blob/master/kradfile.utf8 .  There's another version of that here:  https://github.com/jmettraux/kensaku/blob/master/data/kradfile-u .

EDITED to ADD:

In the comment you asked for code to do this conversion.  As I said there:  The way to do it is to read the file as a sequence of bytes, and look at each byte to characterize it as a separator (space, colon, newline) or JIS X 0208-1997 character. Then translate those JIS X 0208-1997 characters to an encoding you can use. The first part is relatively easy; I don't know how to do the translations, because that encoding isn't in iconvlist().

Here's code to do the first part:

```r
bytes <- readBin("~/temp/kradfile", "int", size=1, signed=FALSE, n=1e6)

# The lines are separated by newline 0x0a values, and the main records
# have 2 byte characters followed by " : ", i.e. 0x20, 0x3a, 0x20.

newline <- 0x0a
space <- 0x20
colon <- 0x3a

newlines <- which(bytes == newline)

# Look through all the lines until we find the main records

for (start in newlines) {
  if (all(bytes[start + 3:5] == c(space, colon, space)))
    break
} 

# Only keep the newlines that start the main records

newlines <- newlines[newlines >= start]

# Now extract the data

result <- vector("list", length = length(newlines))

for (i in seq_along(newlines)) {
  if (i < length(newlines)) {
    kanji <- bytes[newlines[i] + 1:2]
    eol <- newlines[i+1]
    elements <- bytes[(newlines[i] + 6):(eol - 1)]
    # drop the spaces
    elements <- elements[elements != space]
    result[[i]] <- list(kanji = kanji, elements = elements)
  }
}
```

This ends up with a long list that starts like this:

```r
head(result, 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$kanji
#> [1] 176 161
#> 
#> [[1]]$elements
#> [1] 161 195 176 236 184 253
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$kanji
#> [1] 176 162
#> 
#> [[2]]$elements
#> [1] 161 195 176 236 184 253
```

So the first kanji has bytes 176 161, with three elements:  161 195, 176 236, 184 253.  Translating those into readable characters needs a table of the JIS X 0208-1997 encoding, and I don't have that.

2nd EDIT:

After a bit of searching, I found the following.  We  need to subtract 0x80 from the characters in kradfile to get the actual JIS X 0208 encoding.  `iconv()` doesn't support the 1997 revision of that encoding, but it does support the 1990 version, calling it `"JIS_X0208-1990"`.  A tricky bit is that to handle multibyte characters, the bytes for each character need to be in an entry in a list as a raw vector.  So here's the final bit of code to extract the characters from the original file:

```r
for (i in seq_along(result)) {
  code <- as.raw(result[[i]]$kanji - 0x80)
  result[[i]]$kanji <- iconv(list(code), from = "JIS_X0208-1990", to="UTF-8")
  code <- as.raw(result[[i]]$elements - 0x80)
  result[[i]]$elements <- iconv(list(code), from = "JIS_X0208-1990", to="UTF-8")
}
head(result, 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$kanji
#> [1] "亜"
#> 
#> [[1]]$elements
#> [1] "｜一口"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$kanji
#> [1] "唖"
#> 
#> [[2]]$elements
#> [1] "｜一口"
```

Comment: thanks @user2554330 .This does solve my problem. however, for the sake of learning, can one use a loop that decodes the original file correctly ?.

Comment: The way to do it is to read the file as a sequence of bytes, and look at each byte to characterize it as a separator (space, colon, newline) or JIS X 0208-1997 character.  Then translate those JIS X 0208-1997  characters to an encoding you can use.  The first part is relatively easy; I don't know how to do the translations, because that encoding isn't in `iconvlist()`.  I suppose you could use an older revision (I see JIS_X0208-1990) and manually correct any errors.

Comment: I've added some sample code to do the first part.